# pentaho - passing data to a report query

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, parameters, pentaho

Started working with pentaho yesterday

Someone else has made a report and we need to parameterize it.

Have a value in session that i need to pass from jsp to pentaho report so that its passed on to the underlying query ... thus only some data will be shown to current user (that pertains to him)

We have the site ready to login etc using our auth. Have the enterprise version. can ask for support and probably will in a day (running trial version - client has to give us enterprise credentials)

What have i tried - have a query that sees sample report. looking at their docs but lost. saw someting on how to make a jsp included optionally but not sure where the to go for what I need.

Example low level query :

```
 SELECT * FROM `TransformerSurveys` WHERE T_id = 1
```

Want to parameertize the 1 -> need to define it as a prameters, hopefully with a default like 0 so no data is seen if we dont change it. and then a sample where its included in a jsp and changed before rendering. User cannot change the value.

Need a tutorial from making the report using pentaho version 5, from creating xaction ... to jsp in our web app. I have the login part solved ( need to be logged in with a user who has permission to view the report ... but want code and instructions for the rest

Comment: Will add bounty tomorrow - answer now to get a head start to earn it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `${[security:principalName]}` variable to pass the username or `${[session:mySessionVariable]}` to pass another session variable.

Beware of exposing internal variables as parameter reports.

Comment: Do you have sample code/ git hub that uses version 5 of pentaho? I was able to pass a parameter to a interactive report but still like to see how to use in ChartHelper etc with Version 5 api. Npw able to create ILogger and IPentahoUser object ...  updated question with more info

Comment: That's a separate question. And asking for a tutorial doesn't really qualify as a valid question. There are many forums for that, I don't think this is the right one.

Comment: Can you point me to one? added question on the pentaho forum, but i see a lot of quesions threr that are unanswered. or answer as a answer here ...

Comment: http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?162500-pentaho-5-parameter-value-to-intereactive-report-in-view-only

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=cr&ei=chpqU6DvIszXPPCWgIAC#q=pentaho+report+designer+5+tutorial <-- you have quite a few there.